# How to use generic methods in Controller with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I have the following `Controller` in my ASP.NET Core project:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class MainController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("DataQ")
    public List<T> GetData<T>(int id) where T : class => new List<T>() { default(T) };

    [HttpGet("T1")
    public string Testing() => "Testing";
  }
```

As you see, the controller *isn't generic* but it contains a generic method.

With the `HttpGet` attribute I can set what URI will be used on call.

The `Testing` method can be called (so the `Controller` is visible). However, it seems that the generic method does not exist in the controller.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1#sample-generic-controller-feature), only the generic controllers require extra measures to be discoverable:

> By default, ASP.NET Core MVC ignores generic controllers (for example,
>   `SomeController<T>`). This sample uses a controller feature provider
>   that runs after the default provider and adds generic controller
>   instances for a specified list of types (defined in EntityTypes.Types)

Can I somehow call the generic method or I should implement inheriting controllers that call the method?

Comment: How would you want to call such a method from the web? How would you expect to be able to pass `T`?

Comment: @nvoigt I'd expect the actual parameter to be serialized to JSON and in the server side the type of `T` should be _inferred_ from the incoming parameter.

Comment: That does not work in C# code (you cannot infer a `T` from an `int`) so it won't work on the web. Even if you put a `T` in the parameters, that's not how it works. Inferring something means it's known at **compile time**. A compiler cannot infer something that does not happen until after the compilation is done.

Comment: Imagine you pick `T` as parameter and I send a `5.0`, is that a float or a double? Or a decimal? Or maybe an int, because JSON does not even know the difference, it's all number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET does not match parameters the way you expect. It cannot find out which of your classes in your project may or may not fit the JSON sent. You need to give it a specific class it can then match the JSON input against and either succeed or fail.

ASP.NET needs to have a specific controller. That can be a generic controller, but the types need to be known. You cannot have a generic and say "I dunno, the types... just use what comes in". As they need to be known, having a generic method going to the outside is not possible.

You can implement generic controllers as per your link, or you can inherit controllers that call the generic method in their C# code.