# sending an object array to a get function

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .NET Core and WebApi and I am trying to figure out what the url would look like to send an array of objects through.

For example

```
public class DataObject
{
  public int id { get; set;}
  public string name { get; set }
}

[HttpGet()]
public <ActionResult<string>> GetSomething(DataObject[] data))
{
  //do something and return a string
}
```

what would the url look like to do this?  Should I use FromQuery or FromRoute on data? On the HttpGet(), what should be in the parenthesis? "{data}" or something else?

Everything I can find so far has been on integer arrays or string arrays, but not complex arrays to a get call.

Update

Still not able to get this to work even though I'm sure the reply I have gotten should work.  Here is some more code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

 [HttpGet()]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GridResult), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GridResult>> GetGridData<TFilter1, TFilter2, TItem1>
        ([FromQuery]string sessionID, [FromQuery] GridDetails details, [FromQuery] TFilter1[] TFilters1, [FromQuery] TFilter2[] TFilters2, [FromQuery] TItem1[] TSorts)
```

and finally the url that I have generated that throws a 404.

`https://localhost:44366/api/grid/GetGridData/sessionID=598357390&details?NUMBER_OF_ROWS_FIRST_RETURNED=100&CURSOR_POSITION=0&RESULT_IN_SAXORDER=false&TERSERESPONSE=true&IsStaticList=true&GRID_TYPE=list&REQUEST_TYPE=LIST.DATA_ONLY.STORED&GRID_NAME=WUWP09&TFilters1[0].AliasName=PRO_CODE&TFilters1[0].Operator=%3D&TFilters1[0].SEQNUM=1&TFilters1[1].AliasName=APR_CLASS&TFilters1[1].Operator=%3D&Tsorts[1].SEQNUM=2&Tsorts[0].ALIAS_NAME=pvd_value&Tsorts[0].TYPE=ASC`

Update 2

`https://localhost:44366/api/grid/GetGridData?sessionID=598357390&details.NUMBER_OF_ROWS_FIRST_RETURNED=100&details.CURSOR_POSITION=0&details.RESULT_IN_SAXORDER=false&details.TERSERESPONSE=true&details.IsStaticList=true&details.GRID_TYPE=list&details.REQUEST_TYPE=LIST.DATA_ONLY.STORED&details.GRID_NAME=WUWP09&details.TAB_NAME&details.LOCALIZE_RESULT&details.USER_FUNCTION_NAME&details.TOTALRECORDS&details.RES_IsMoreRecords&details.RES_CURRENT_CURSOR_POSITION&TFilters1[0].AliasName=PRO_CODE&TFilters1[0].Operator=%3D&TFilters1[0].SEQNUM=1&TFilters1[1].AliasName=APR_CLASS&TFilters1[1].Operator=%3D&Tsorts[1].SEQNUM=2&Tsorts[0].ALIAS_NAME=pvd_value&Tsorts[0].TYPE=ASC`

Update 3

Startup.cs
     public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var _accessor = services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        var config = new GridServices.Models.config();
        Configuration.Bind("Connections", config);
        services.AddSingleton(config);
        services.AddSingleton(new Controllers.GridController(config));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

GridController

```
namespace EAMWebApi.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class GridController : ControllerBase
{
    config Config { get; }
    //private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    public GridController(config config)
    {
        config = Config;
        //_linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GridResult), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GridResult>> GetGridData<TFilter1, TFilter2, TItem1>
        ([FromQuery]string sessionID, [FromQuery] GridDetails details, [FromQuery] TFilter1[] TFilters1 = null, [FromQuery] TFilter2[] TFilters2 = null, [FromQuery] TItem1[] TSorts = null)
    {//Do something}
}
```

GridDetails

```
namespace GridServices.Models
{
    public class GridDetails
    {
        public string GRID_NAME { get; set; }
        public string NUMBER_OF_ROWS_FIRST_RETURNED { get; set; }        
        public string CURSOR_POSITION { get; set; }        
        public string TAB_NAME { get; set; }        
        public string RESULT_IN_SAXORDER { get; set; }        
        public string TERSERESPONSE { get; set; }        
        public string LOCALIZE_RESULT { get; set; }        
        public string USER_FUNCTION_NAME { get; set; }        
        public string TOTALRECORDS { get; set; }        
        public bool RES_IsMoreRecords { get; set; }        
        public bool IsStaticList { get; set; }        
        public string GRID_TYPE { get; set; }        
        public string REQUEST_TYPE { get; set; }        
        public string RES_CURRENT_CURSOR_POSITION { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MultiAddOnFilter

```
public class MultiAddOnFilter
{        
    public string ALIAS_NAME { get; set; }
    public string OPERATOR { get; set; }
    public string OPERATORSpecified { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public string LPAREN { get; set; }
    public string RPAREN { get; set; }        
    public string JOINER { get; set; }        
    public string JOINERSpecified { get; set; }        
    public string SEQNUM { get; set; }

    public MultiAddOnFilter(string _ALIAS_NAME, string _OPERATOR, string _VALUE)
    {
        ALIAS_NAME = _ALIAS_NAME;
        OPERATOR = _OPERATOR;
        OPERATORSpecified = "true";
        VALUE = _VALUE;
    }
}
```

Sorts
    namespace GridServices.Models
{
    public class Sort
    {
        public string ALIAS_NAME { get; set; }
        public string TYPE { get; set; }
        public string TYPESpecified { get; set; }

```
    public Sort(string _ALIAS_NAME, string _TYPE)
    {
        ALIAS_NAME = _ALIAS_NAME;
        TYPE = _TYPE;
        TYPESpecified = "true";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what would the url look like to do this?*

It should be something like the following:

```
GET /Somecontroller/GetSomething?data[0].id=1&data[0].name=nameA&data[1].id=2&data[1].name=nameB&data[2].id=3&data[2].name=nameC
```

**This payload is almost the same as you post in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, except you'll send it as a querystring.**

---

**[Edit]**

> *If one of those items were to be empty, would I have to pass %00 to it to indicate a null value?*

1. Let's say you have such an object array:

```
data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "nameA"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": null            
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "nameC"
  }
]
```

Note the `data[1].name==null`. you don't have to specify `data[1].name` :

```
?data[0].id=1&data[0].name=nameA&data[1].id=2&data[2].id=3&data[2].name=nameC
```

2. If the whole `data[1]` item is `null`, just adjust the index of `data[2]` to `data[1]`:

```
data[0].id=1&data[0].name=nameA&data[1].id=3&data[1].name=name
```

Or you could add an empty field for this item:

```
?data[0].id=1&data[0].name=nameA&data[1].id=&data[2].id=3&data[2].name=nameC
```

> *What if the whole DataObject was null? /GetSomething?data=%00 ?*

you don't have to specify `/GetSomething?data=%00`, just send a request to `/GetSomething?`, and then you'll get an empty array.

---

**[Edit2]**

There're two reasons that always routes you to a 404 result:

1. You're registering your `GridController` as a **singleton**. MVC will register controllers automatically (as a **scoped** service). Just remove that line :

```
services.AddSingleton(new Controllers.GridController(config));
```

2. Your controller action of `GetGridData<TFilter1, TFilter2, TItem1>` is a **generic** method. It won't work by default. There's already [a thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873307/how-to-use-generic-methods-in-controller-with-asp-net-core) talking about this. I would also suggest you use a specific GridFilter type for each method. If you find yourself repeating the same logic, you could put your generic method into a parent `MySupperGridBaseController<TFilter1, TFilter2, TItem1>` class, something as below:

```
public class MySupperGridBaseController<TFilter1, TFilter2, TItem1> : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<GridResult>> GetGridData
            ([FromQuery]string sessionID, [FromQuery] GridDetails details, [FromQuery] TFilter1[] TFilters1 = null, [FromQuery] TFilter2[] TFilters2 = null, [FromQuery] TItem1[] TSorts = null)
    {
         ...
    }
}


// now we could reuse the same logic inherited from parent 
public class GridController : MySupperGridBaseController<MultiAddOnFilter, MultiAddOnFilter, Sort>
{

}
```

Comment: If one of those items were to be empty, would I have to pass %00 to it to indicate a null value?  What if the whole DataObject was null? /GetSomething?data=%00 ?

Comment: I got distracted from this for a while by another project at work.  I am still struggling to get the url to work properly.  I have tried to create a LinkGenerator to do it for me, but there are no good examples of how to use this anywhere.  I get stuck passing the LinkGenerator into the constructor of my controller that I am injecting.

Comment: please see my updated question.  I want to mark your answer as answer, but I still can't get this to work.

Comment: @TheOriginalCole Your updated controller has a `[Route]` that requires a url like `api/[controller]/[action]`, but what you sent to server is `/api/grid/GetGridData/sessionID=598357390&details?....` . Could you please try `/api/grid/GetGridData?sessionID=598357390&details&....` ?

Comment: So I tried what you suggested and still 404.  I had some parameters in details that were blank, so I added them in Postman and came up with the following that was still a 404.  See above question for update. it's too long to post in a comment.

Comment: @TheOriginalCole Typically, the payload won't make you get a 404. I guess there is a problem about routing (instead of model binding). So... could you please post the code of controller as well as all the related models ? Also, it would be nicer if you show us how you configure the MVC routes within Startup.cs.

Comment: I have added the code.  I am new to .net core and web api, but up until this I had been fine as most other calls were fairly simple, and I was able to get them to work.

Comment: @TheOriginalCole It's hard to post it as a comment. So I update my answer.  please check :)

Comment: That did it!  Once I did as you suggested and removed the blank parameters, it called.  Had a null reference exception inside the call, but that is something I can figure out on my own!  Thank you so much for your help, saved me loads of time and pain!

Comment: I did have to keep the injection of the controller however.  It was the only way to pass configuration in.  Whether or not it should be a singleton is another story.

Comment: @TheOriginalCole You don't have to :).  The DI container will inject the controller as well as the Configuration automatically if you register the configuration.

Comment: I think my issue that I am having after looking at other threads is that I am binding configuration to a data object, where as the examples I am finding just go after the configuration directly.  I'm not sure what is a better approach. [link to SO thread as to how you suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @TheOriginalCole Your way by ` var config = new GridServices.Models.config();  Configuration.Bind("Connections", config);`  works, but  I would suggest we should always use the DI. To be specific, I would suggest we should use the IOptions pattern if possible.  DI makes life easy when you want to create an instance that has dependencies on other services while some of them might depend on other services. Manually configuration (or new it) works, but it will be rather complex when our code grows.

Comment: I am working in a microservice architecture in this case where each project has it's own config, so in this case, it should be ok.  But I see your point if it is a larger application.